# CSS media queries vs. background image width

Tags: css, mobile, background-image, media-queries

I'm trying to use media queries for the first time in my life. What I want to achieve is an online form for mobile browers (basically for Android MDPI / HPDI and iPhone 3 to 4).

What I did is to do a media query for 320px screens with a 320px width background image, this way :

```
@media only screen
and (min-device-width : 120px)
and (max-device-width : 320px)
{

body {
    background-image:url('../img/bg-320.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 320px;
    height: 436px;
    margin:0; padding:0; border:0;
}
```

and also, on the same css, another media query for small screens (less than 480px width) with a 480px width background image, this way :

```
@media only screen
and (min-device-width : 320px)
and (max-device-width : 480px)
{


body {
    background-image:url('bg-480.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 480px;
    height: 800px;
    margin:0; padding:0; border:0;
}
```

The detection works fine, but the problem is that the 480-width devices they zoom the 480px background, as it were way too big for their screen, which is a non-sense!

Even stranger, if if try to load the 320px-CSS-block (the first one up above) on the 480-width devices, then it works fine! No zoom! But obviously, the image is a bit blurred.

This happens on my iPod Touch and my HTC Desire too.

Can anyone help me please?

By the way, my header looks like :

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Frameset//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/frameset.dtd">
<html>

<head>

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />  

    <link type="text/css" href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />

</head>
```

*EDIT:*

I just realized that media queries don't have anything to do my issue.

The problem is basically : **why, on two 480px-width devices, a 320px-width-background-image is seen as full screen, while a 480px-width-background-image is zoomed?** This is just a non-sense!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, target-densitydpi=device-dpi, user-scalable=no" />
```

Everything is extremely well explained on this article http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/targeting.html

Answer (score 0):

You can control target dpi aswell with meta tags. You should give it a try or with different density values:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, target-densitydpi=160dpi, initial-scale=1.0">`